# how to install fltk with codeblocks

Tags: c++, codeblocks, fltk

I selected new FLTK project in codeblocks. I chose a name for the project, later it asked me for the location of the folder having FLTK. I pointed it to the tar.gz file which i had downloaded into a folder on the (D) drive, and clicked next. 
It says

"The path you entered seems valid but the wizard can't locate include directory."

PS: I am using windows 7.

How do I fix this problem? How can I install it?

Comment: I cross checked, the folder i pointed to has the tar.gz file that i downloaded from 

http://www.fltk.org/software.php

Comment: It is not easy because fltk.org does not provide the binary package (for a reason). However, you can build the source package you mention using Code::Blocks, and use it. I may write a short explanation how to do this next week as it may be helpful to other FLTK/Code::Blocks users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell the IDE to use a compressed archive. You have to unpack it, and possibly build it if it's not built. There should be finished packages for Windows that contains the header files and libraries (and possibly DLL's) needed.